# string matching function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've to match a string with strings in a column of mysql table, i need to select the strings which has more than 80% of match. is there any function in mysql will do this?

for example "quote by placing" string matches more than 80% for the string"quote by place". Like this i've filter.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a special reason for "80%"?  can you give us some background on what you're  doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A FULLTEXT search would probably be the best approach for what you're doing. No need to pick an arbitrary % otherwise.

If you're doing more intensive searching check out some of the engines like Sphinx

Comment: i think the best way is using 'like' and match 80% for the result what i get. is it correct.

Comment: By using similar_text($str1,$str2,$match) function on search results will give some optimum result i wanted, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use PHP functions like that to analyze your results for the exact % match

Answer (score 0):

try chopping 20% of a string in php and then use `like` for 80% of your string and all strings to compare

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think he wants 80% that appears anywhere, not just the start.  So cutting it would only compare a certain 80% that you pick

Comment: @babonk yes, i just want to match 80% anywhere on the string not the start

Comment: oh, so i'm sorry for misunderstanding the question

Comment: @banonk i want to some options to be selected by default on the basis of this match.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the MYSQL soundex function that may give you what you need

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your criteria, you want a fuzzy search. This is not implemented in MySQL. You will have to find a way to externalize the check for this.